# Permission from subproject manifest affecting to main project

Tags: android, permissions, gradle, manifest

Recently I've added Optimobile SDK to the project in which I'm working, because a request of marketing guys.

After adding it and install new apk on my device.. I noticed that there's two new permissions added to my application, capability of sending SMS without user interaction and capability of sending calls.

I have been looking into my code and found these permission but on OptiMobile SDK manifest:

```
<!-- Enables sending text messages from ads (user input only)-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

<!-- Enables triggering phone calls from ads (user input only) -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

**Question is.. there's any way to avoid getting the permissions declared on inner projects manifests ?**

P.D.:

- Optimobile SDK have the name "gujemssdk" -> https://code.google.com/p/gujemssdk/
- I'm using gradle, maybe that's a useful point to know..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the first question is: will Optimobile SDK work without those permissions? Ideally, they would not have those in their AAR's manifest if they did not need them.

Assuming that you think it will work, you should be able to add those own elements to your app's manifest, with `tools:node="remove"`, to [get the manifest merging process to remove them](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-Element-Removal):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" tools:node="remove" />
```